mclapply with a "while" loop
In scientific computing I often want to run loops indefinitely when looking for a possible counterexample, such as
repeat{ 
   x = runif(1)
   if(x>1)break
}

I also want to use parallel::mclapply to take advantage of multiple cores. Is there a way to do this?
I would rather not create a huge vector e.g., parallel::mclapply(1:1e9, ...) for memory reasons and anyway it isn't really an endless loop.
In other words, is it possible to run an indefinite loop with lapply or parallel:mcapply? Maybe some undocumented way to fiddle with the vector passed to the mclapply from within the loop?

Your question is too vague; I suggest you provide a minimal, reproducible example that illustrates how you do it with repeat { ... }. That will increase the chances for someone to give you constructive feedback.  I also suggest that you try to achieve the same with lapply(). If you can get it to work with lapply(), then it's likely it'll run in parallel, otherwise not.

lapply() fundamentally cannot model an infinite loop — but your loop is also not infinite (it has a break statement). Still, it’s a completely different algorithm than that modelled by a vector application.

@KonradRudolph That there is an infinite loop by any definition

@Hasse1987 In your placeholder code, yes. But surely that’s not the actual code you’re writing, since that code is completely useless… I have to admit that I also don’t understand your question’s first sentence. I’ve done my bit of scientific computing and I have never seen anybody do this. “looking for counterexamples” in this way doesn’t seem useful. You’d normally use actual sampling or something along these lines.

A quick and dirty approach using job::job called in a loop for as many times as cores you want to use. When any of them finds a counterexample, it will finish. You can have it silently return whatever you need. Once one of the jobs completes, you can cancel the remainder using the "Background Jobs" tab in the RStudio console.
Alternatively, you can automate that last part by checking for a returned variable and restarting R to kill the remaining background jobs. If you're up for working out a more sophisticated approach, see the comments.
For example, let's see if runif can return 1703756793*2^-32:
set.seed(0)
(x <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 1703756793
(x <- x*2^-32)
#> [1] 0.3966868

for (j in 1:(parallel::detectCores() - 1)) {
  job::job({
    jobid <- j
    i <- 1
    while (all(runif(1e6) != x)) {i <- i + 1}
    job::export(c(i, jobid))
  }, import = c(x, j))
}

while(!exists("i")) {}
while(is.null(i)) {}
save.image() # save to ~/.RData in case the session disconnects
.rs.restartR() # restart R (kills the remaining background jobs)

After R restarts, the global environment will contain the variable i and jobid. (For example, I got i = 55 and jobid = 7, meaning x was found in the 55th batch of the 7th job.)

while(is.null(i)) {} is unnecessary, and while(!exists("i")) {} is extremely wasteful (it basically keeps one CPU core completely occupied with busywork, and can’t be cancelled gracefully). I don’t know the ‘job’ package but all good asynchronous frameworks have a notification mechanism that can e.g. inform the calling process of a change in status. If ‘job’ is missing these features you could drastically improve the computational load by letting the main process sleep and awake inside a loop.

@KonradRudolph, those last four lines would let you kick off the counterexample search and walk away. Once one of the jobs finds a solution, it would kill all the others. Yes, one of the cores would be occupied checking that a solution was found. If you have a better way to accomplish this, I'd be genuinely interested in seeing it.  while(is.null(i)) {} was there because I thought I would sometimes get NULL for i. On retesting, that doesn't seem to be the case, so it can probably be safely removed.

Like I said, a better way would be to use notifications (e.g. semaphores or condition variables). That’s literally what they are there for. (Incidentally this would also be a cleaner solution than killing the other subprocesses.) The mechanism is implemented e.g. by the ‘nanonext’ package.

It does appear that would be a better way ... after working through what looks like a non-trivial learning curve. Maybe someone will feel up to the effort to apply it here and post the result.
